# jQuery draggable(), resizable() in jsf doesn't work perfectly

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm having a problem with jQuery: resizable() and draggable. When I move the div on datatable works perfectly and when I resize too, but after resize if drag the div it moves 1px on top and 1px on left. I can do this from the container div on top of the page. The divs on the rich:dataTable had been generated from jsf with h:outputtext/escape=false

I have considered this bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4696 and this http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2793 and I have applied the patches

This is my xhtml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
<title>TC</title>
<h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" />
<h:outputScript name="jquery.js" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="resources/js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.json-2.4.js" />

<style type="text/css">
 .ui-resizable {
position: relative;
 }

 .ui-resizable-handle {
position: absolute;
font-size: 0.1px;
z-index: 99999;
display: block;
 }

 .ui-resizable-e {
cursor: e-resize;
width: 2px;
right: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
 }

</style>
</h:head>
<h:body>

<a4j:outputPanel rendered="false">
    <rich:dataTable/>
</a4j:outputPanel>

<h:form id="formulario">


    <script type="text/javascript"> 

   function extenderHoras(div, index){
var contenedor = '#'+div.id;
var left = jQuery(contenedor).css("left");
var contenedorPadre = jQuery(contenedor).parent();
var padreDePadre = jQuery(contenedorPadre).parent();
var cantidadHijos = contenedorPadre[0].childElementCount;
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e){
       window.mouseXPos = e.pageX;
       window.mouseYPos = e.pageY;
    }); 


jQuery(contenedor).droppable({
    accept: ".ui-draggable-dragging",
    tolerance: 'pointer'
    }).resizable({
    handles: 'e', 
    minWidth: 41,
    grid: [ 41, 0 ], 
    containment: contenedorPadre,
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
        if(!index){
            //Si no tiene index 
            var divArray = new Array();
            var colorDiv = div.style.background;
            var idPadreDePadre = padreDePadre[0].id;
            var fila = idPadreDePadre.split(':');
            index = fila[2];//Obtenemos el index

            var cantidadHijosDiv = contenedorPadre[0].childElementCount; //Obtenemos Todos los hijos que se tiene en la fila
            cantidadHijosDiv = cantidadHijosDiv - 1; //La lista es empieza desde 0 se le quita un elemento (tamaño -1)
            var sumaTotalDiv = 0;
            if(cantidadHijosDiv==0){//Si solo tiene un hijo obtenemos el tamaño de ese hijo para ponerlo como margen del div que estamos colocando
                sumaTotalDiv = contenedorPadre[0].children[cantidadHijosDiv].style.width;
                sumaTotalDiv = sumaTotalDiv.replace('px','');
            }else{//Si tiene más de un hijo tenemos que recorrer el arreglo y sumar el tamaño de todos los div 
                for(var i = 0; i &lt;= cantidadHijosDiv; i++){
                    var ancho = contenedorPadre[0].children[i].style.width;
                    sumaTotalDiv = sumaTotalDiv + parseInt(ancho.replace('px',''));
                }
            }
            var leftUbicacion = sumaTotalDiv * -1;
            var csstxt = jQuery(div.id).css('cssText') + ';top:0;left:'+leftUbicacion+' px;background-color:'+colorDiv+';height:'+ui.element.height()+'; width:'+ui.element.width()+';float:left;margin-left:'+sumaTotalDiv;
            jQuery(div.id).css('cssText', csstxt);
        } else {
            jQuery(contenedor).css({
                'width': ui.element.width(),
                'height': ui.element.height(),
                'top': ui.element[0].style.top,
                'left': ui.element[0].style.left,
                'float': 'left',
                position: 'absolute'
            });
        };
        var divArray = [{
                "id":ui.element[0].id,
                "width":ui.element[0].style.width,
                "height":ui.element[0].style.height,
                "top":ui.element[0].style.top,
                "left":ui.element[0].style.left,
                "right":ui.element[0].style.right,
                "top":ui.element[0].style.top,
                "backgroundColor":ui.element[0].style.background
        }];

        var json = jQuery.toJSON(divArray);
        convertirJson(json, index);
    }
}).draggable({
    containment: contenedorPadre,
    grid: [ 41, 0 ],
    revert: 'valid',
    stop: function(event, ui) {

        if(!cantidadHijos){
            //Si no tiene hijos que no haga nada, por si lo coloca en otro lado que no sea la tabla
        } else {

        }
    }
}).removeClass("ui-draggable");
}

function arrastrarALado(div){
var contenedor = '#'+div.id;
var colorDiv = div.style.background;
jQuery(contenedor).draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'valid',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var elem = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);
        event.stopPropagation();
        var tag = elem.tagName;
        var cantidadHijosDiv = elem.childElementCount; //Obtenemos Todos los hijos que se tiene en la fila
        cantidadHijosDiv = cantidadHijosDiv - 1; //quitamos un elemento men la lista es (tamaño -1)
        var sumaTotalDiv = 0;
        if(cantidadHijosDiv==0){//Si solo tiene un hijo obtenemos el tamaño de ese hijo para ponerlo como margen del div que estamos colocando
            sumaTotalDiv = elem.children[cantidadHijosDiv].style.width;
            sumaTotalDiv = sumaTotalDiv.replace('px','');
        }
        else{//Si tiene más de un hijo tenemos que recorrer el arreglo y sumar el tamaño de todos los div 
            for(var i = 0; i &lt;= cantidadHijosDiv; i++){
                var ancho = elem.children[i].style.width;
                sumaTotalDiv = sumaTotalDiv + parseInt(ancho.replace('px',''));
            }
        }
        var divHijo = elem.children[cantidadHijosDiv];//Obtenemos el último hijo de la lista
        if(!divHijo){//Si es undefined no tiene hijos o ha puesta fuera de la barra - Propenso a cambios
            alert('No puede colocar la barra aquí');
        } else if(divHijo.tagName=='TH'){//Si el hijo 
            alert('No puede colocar la barra aquí');
        } 
        else if(divHijo.tagName=='SPAN'){//Si el hijo es un SPAN es que crea richfaces
            var divHijo = elem.children[cantidadHijosDiv+1];//obtenemos el siguiente hijo, solo ocurre en el caso de que sea el span padre
            divHijo = divHijo.id;
        } else {//Si no usamos el nombre del ultimo div
            divHijo = divHijo.id;
        }
        if(tag == 'TD'){
            var leftUbicacion = sumaTotalDiv * -1;
            var divNuevo = divHijo+cantidadHijosDiv+div.id;
            //Implementando cssText de Jquery ya que no se puede insertar el estilo de forma normal al crear el div, tengo que agregarlo  
            var csstxt = jQuery('#'+divNuevo).css('cssText') + ';top:0;left:'+leftUbicacion+' !important;background-color:'+colorDiv+';height:25px; width:82px;float:left;margin-left:'+sumaTotalDiv;
            jQuery('<div/>', {
                    id: divNuevo, //obtenemos el ultimo hijo, luego le ponemos la cantidad y el id del div que estoy arrastrando
                    //onmousedown: 'arrastrarBarra(this);',
                    onmouseover: 'extenderHoras(this);'
            }).appendTo(elem);
            jQuery('#'+divNuevo).css('cssText', csstxt);
        } 
    }
});
}



</script>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="convertirJson" 
        action="#{pruebasmb.obtenerDiv()}" >
        <a4j:param name="divArray" assignTo="#{pruebasmb.divJSON}" ></a4j:param>
        <a4j:param name="index" assignTo="#{pruebasmb.indexPersonaSeleccionada}"></a4j:param>
    </a4j:jsFunction>

<div id="contenedores" style="width: 600px; height: 30px; background-color: #f0f0f0; ">
<div id="divBlue" style="width: 82px; height: 25px; background-color: blue; float: left; "  onmouseover="arrastrarALado(this);"></div>
<div id="divRojo" style="width: 82px; height: 25px; background-color: red; float: left; "  onmouseover="arrastrarALado(this);"></div>
<div id="divVerde" style="width: 82px; height: 25px; background-color: green; float: left; "  onmouseover="arrastrarALado(this);"></div>
</div>


    <a4j:commandButton action="#{pruebasmb.llenarlista()}"
        value="Llenar lista" render="dataTablePersonas"></a4j:commandButton>

    <br />
    <br />
    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="false">
        <rich:dataTable var="persona" value="#{pruebasmb.personas}" 
            id="dataTablePersonas" rowKeyVar="index">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <rich:columnGroup>
                    <rich:column rowspan="2" >
                        <h:outputText value="Persona" style="padding: 0px;" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column colspan="24" style="padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="Horas" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column breakRowBefore="true"
                        style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="00h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="00h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="01h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="01h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="02h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="02h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="03h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="03h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="04h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="04h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="05h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="05h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="06h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="06h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="07h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="07h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="08h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="08h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="09h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="09h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="10h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="10h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="11h00" />
                    </rich:column>
                    <rich:column style="width: 40px; padding: 0px;">
                        <h:outputText value="11h30" />
                    </rich:column>
                </rich:columnGroup>
            </f:facet>

            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText  value="#{persona.apellido}" />
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column colspan="24" style="padding: 0px; height:25px; position: relative;" >
    <h:outputText  value="#{pruebasmb.divDefault.get(index)}" escape="false" />
            </rich:column>
        </rich:dataTable>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

pruebasmb Bean

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import java.lang.reflect.Type;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
 import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


 import com.google.gson.Gson;
 import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;



    @ManagedBean(name = "pruebasmb")
    @SessionScoped
    public class PruebasMB implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2290961655122569612L;
private List<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();
private String valorDelSlider;
private String celdaClickeada;
private String estiloBarra;
private String indexPersonaSeleccionada;
private EstilosCss estilos = new EstilosCss();
private List<String> divDefault = new ArrayList<String>();
private String divJSON;

public void llenarlista() {
    divDefault.clear();
    personas.clear();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Integer horasTrabajadas;
        // Para generar un temporal de las horas trabajadas aleatoriamente
        horasTrabajadas = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 16));
        if (horasTrabajadas == 0)
            horasTrabajadas = 1;
        else
            horasTrabajadas = horasTrabajadas * 41;
        estiloBarra = estilos.generarEstilo(horasTrabajadas.toString(), "25", "yellow", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "left", null, null);
        Persona p = new Persona("nombre" + i, "apellido" + i, i + 20, "Calle J y la " + i, estiloBarra, horasTrabajadas, (i/2));
        generarBarras(p, horasTrabajadas, i);
        personas.add(p);
    }
}

public void obtenerDiv(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Div>>(){}.getType();
    List<Div> div = gson.fromJson(divJSON.toString(), type);

    Integer index = Integer.valueOf(indexPersonaSeleccionada);
    if(index==null){
        index=0;
    }

    valorDelSlider = div.get(0).getWidth().replace("px", "");
    System.out.println("Width: "+div.get(0).getWidth());

    Integer valor = Integer.valueOf(valorDelSlider);
    int valorTemporal = valor;
    int horasTrabajadas = personas.get(index).getHorasTrabajadas();
    if (horasTrabajadas == 1) {
        valor = valor - 1;
        valorTemporal = valorTemporal - 1;
        valor = valor / 82;
    } else
        valor = valor / 82;
    if ((valorTemporal % 82) > 0) {
        System.out.println("El total de horas es " + valor + " y media ");
    } else
        System.out.println("Ha realizado " + valor + " horas");
    System.out.println(valor * 82);
    estiloBarra = "left: 0px; background-color: yellow; height: 25px; width: " + (valor * 82) + "px; top: 0px !important; float: left;";
    personas.get(index).setEstiloUsuario(estiloBarra);
}

public void generarBarras(Persona p, Integer horasTrabajadas, Integer i) {
    Integer horasSegundoDiv=0;

    String rgb="";
    String estiloBarra2 ="";
    String div ="";

    for(int j = 0; j<= 2; j ++){

        horasSegundoDiv = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 16));
        if (horasSegundoDiv == 0)
            horasSegundoDiv = 1;
        else
            horasSegundoDiv = horasSegundoDiv * 41;

        rgb = Color2Hex();
        estiloBarra2 = estilos.generarEstilo(horasSegundoDiv.toString(), "25", rgb, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "left", null, null);
        div = div + "<div id='nombrediv" + i+"_"+j + "' style='" + estiloBarra2 + "' onmouseover='extenderHoras(this," + (i) + ");'> </div>";
    }
    divDefault.add(div);
}

/**
 * Se genera un color al azar en rgb y se convierte a hexadecimal
 * 
 * @return Color en hexadecimal
 */
public String Color2Hex() {
    int R = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 256));
    int G = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 256));
    int B = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 256));
    Color c = new Color(R, G, B);
    String rgb = Integer.toHexString(c.getRGB() & 0xffffff);
    if(rgb.length()<6)
        rgb = "0"+rgb;
    return "#"+rgb;
}

         //getter and setter
        }
```

and Estilos.css where I generate the Style of div

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

    public class EstilosCss implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1279423720796129516L;
private String width;
private String height;
private String backgroundColor;
private String leftMargin;
private String rightMargin;
private String left;
private String right;
private String top;
private String bottom;
private String floatEstilo;
private String gradientColor1;
private String gradientColor2;



public String generarEstilo(String width, String height, String backgroundColor, String leftMargin, String rightMargin, String left, String right,
        String top, String bottom, String floatEstilo, String gradientColor1, String gradientColor2) {

    String estilo = "";
    estilo = "width:" + width + "px; height:" + height + "px; background-color:" + backgroundColor + "; left-margin:" + leftMargin
    + "px; right-margin:" + rightMargin + "px; left:" + left + "px; right:" + right + "px; top:" + top + "px; bottom:" + bottom + "px; float:"+floatEstilo+" !important;";

    //Si ingresa los colores del gradient del div
    if(gradientColor1!=null&&gradientColor2!=null){
        estilo = estilo + "background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, "+gradientColor1+" 0%, "+gradientColor2 +" 100%);";
        estilo = estilo + "background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, "+gradientColor1+" 0%, "+gradientColor2 +" 100%);";
        estilo = estilo + "background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, "+gradientColor1+" 0%, "+gradientColor2 +" 100%);";
        estilo = estilo + "background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, "+gradientColor1+"),  color-stop(1,"+gradientColor2 +"));";
        estilo = estilo + "background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, "+gradientColor1+" 0%, "+gradientColor2 +" 100%);";
        estilo = estilo + "background-image: linear-gradient(to top, "+gradientColor1+" 0%, "+gradientColor2 +" 100%);";
        estilo = estilo + "filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='"+gradientColor1+"', endColorstr='"+gradientColor2 +"');";
    }

    return estilo;
}

     //getter and setter

         }
```